# Textfield magnifying glass issue iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, textfield, copy-paste

Will disabling the magnifying glass cause my app to be rejected on app store? I want to disable it to disable copy and paste menu.

Anyone knows how to disable copy and paste menu from the textfields on a Webview?

Answer (score 0):

u just have to add in css:

```
body{
-webkit-user-select:none;
}
```

app store will not reject it.